# Mask Input phone number in PHP

Tags: input, mask

I am new to PHP
All I want to do is Mask Input the phone number
somehow it wouldn't allow Javascript or Jquery

```
$_SESSION["oh"]["phone"]=(empty($_SESSION["oh"]["phone"]))?$_COOKIE["phone"]:$_SESSION["oh"]["phone"];
```

Comment: confuse about 'mask', can you create an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow kind of patterns to mask the phone and to validate it

```
$pattern = "/^([1]-)?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/i"
```

[Reference](http://plasticbrain.net/resources/php-validate-email-address-and-phone-number/)

AFAIK , we  have used the mask() from jquery it helps to validate it

```
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

Its handy to use it